# How to get words that exactly match a pattern using regular expressions

Tags: java, .net, regex

I need to get words that match a particular pattern I give using regex.

For example if the pattern is "ABC", I need to get word string "ABC" if it is in input content.

Content:

> this is **ABC** title. topic name is ABCDE.
>
> My book has page with name BE-ABC.
> **ABC** is a tag name.

I should get `ABC` as the words bolded above. It should return match `ABC` from `ABCDE` or `BE-ABC`

Do I need to use singleline or multiline mode to achieve this?

Comment: Why not `yourString.contains("ABC")` instead of a regex? In this particular case you don't need a regex

Comment: My requirement is i will have a pattern ### not exactly "ABC"

Comment: So, `yourString.contains(pattern)`, `ABC` was just an example

Comment: does contains method in string class supports pattern matching ?i dont think so

Answer (score 2):

As BackSlash mentions, you should use `yourString.contains("ABC")`.

Otherwise, if you really need a regex:

```
.*ABC.*
```

`.` matches any character (except newline) and `*` means zero or more times. Thus, `.*` means zero or more of any character.

`ABC` are literal characters and once again, `.*` appears.

You can test this regex at http://regex101.com/r/yD3rX2

Both of the methods I state will let you know if the string does contain the characters, "ABC", however they will not return the characters "ABC". In most case you would want a boolean value instead.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in a function and call it

```
if(yourString.contains(pattern)) //patern is passed as argument and is type string
return pattern;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\s*ABC\s*
```

meaning optionally any whitespace then ABC and optionally any whitespace.  It sounds like you only want EXACT matches for ABC?

See below for a good regular expressions cheat sheet:

http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: @Dreek Yes i want exact match  the pattern i give.

Comment: So does my regex work for you?

Comment: @Dreek the regex which u gave doesnt work for me. As it will get ABC even from the string "ABCD"

Comment: I have edited the answer above.  Sorry.... it should have been:     \s*ABC\s*

Answer (score 0):

If you need match only ABC as whole words, use:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b(ABC)\\b", Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(yourString);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention whether the pattern could also contain non-alphanumeric characters.
If this is the case, for a general solution I'd suggest using `Regex.Escape(pattern)` to make it an exact literal match, e.g:

```
string inputString = "BE-ABCDE"
string literalToMatch = "ABC";
string escapedPattern = Regex.Escape(literalToMatch);
Regex regex = new Regex(escapedPattern);
Match match = r.Match(inputString);
//...Process appropriately - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx
```